# Trying to port pie chart example to v4 of d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to port [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1203641) to d3 v4 and I am getting stuck because it is drawing a weird triangle in the pie chart. My version is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/pebblexe/f289fd9dfbdc305c00732121179c00c2).

I am getting 3 errors that look like this:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…280223e-14,-100LNaN,NaNZ".
```

and I am unsure of how to proceed.

Thank you for your time and patience in reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help others, but I found a decent pie chart with text at the middle of the radius of the pie graph [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ragingsquirrel3/qkHK6/).

The relevant code is:

```
arcs.append("svg:text").attr("transform", function(d){
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = r;
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";}).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text( function(d, i) {
    return data[i].label;}
        );
```